# Exception: LogStash::ConfigurationError

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Am trying to connect Oracle database via logstash and am getting below error.

```
  Error: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver not loaded. Are you sure you've included the correct jdbc driver in :jdbc_driver_library?
  Exception: LogStash::ConfigurationError
  Stack: D:/softwares/logstash-6.2.4/logstash-6.2.4/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.9/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc.rb:162:in `open_jdbc_connection'
```

Please find my logstash config file :

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "D:\data\ojdbc14.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"
    jdbc_user => "user_0ne"
    jdbc_password => "xxxyyyzzz"
    statement => "SELECT * FROM PRODUCT"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "my_index"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

logstash config file : (corrected)

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "D:\Karthikeyan\data\ojdbc14.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"  // problem in this line is corrected
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"
    jdbc_user => "vb"
    jdbc_password => "123456"
    statement => "SELECT * FROM VB_PRODUCT"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "my_index"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can validate the configuration file using,

```
./user/share/logstash/bin/logstash -f etc/logstash/conf.d/sample.conf --config.test_and_exit
```